# How can I remove $data, $parent etc. from the DOM (KnockoutJS)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, custom-binding, knockout-3.0

I have just started using knockout so if some stuff is ugly please do tell me!

One thing I really want to do is get rid of $parent, $data etc. from the DOM if possible.

I have seen ways to do this elsewhere but can't remember where.

Snippet is attached, if someone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```js
//used to abstract out the jQuery dependancies - just in case at some point in the future jQUery is replaced with another library.
function activeClassSingle(element, standardClass, activeClass){
    $(element).siblings().removeClass(activeClass).addClass(standardClass);
    $(element).removeClass(standardClass).addClass(activeClass);
}



//helper class in a helper file
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonGroupChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
    viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                click: function () {
                    value(allBindingsAccessor.get('val'));
                }
            }
        };
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor,
        allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
    viewModel, bindingContext) {          
        if (allBindingsAccessor.get("val") == ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
           activeClassSingle(element, "btn-info", "btn-success");
        }        
    }
}

//raw data
 var adults = [
    {val: 1, text: "1"},
    {val: 2, text: "2"},
    {val: 3, text: "3"},
    {val: 4, text: "4"},
    {val: 5, text: "5"},
    {val: 6, text: "5+"}
    ];


//viewmodel etc.
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.adultsNo = ko.observable(2);
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-bind="foreach: adults">
            <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bind="buttonGroupChecked: $parent.adultsNo, val: $data.val, text: $data.text"></div>
        </div>
        <span data-bind="text: adultsNo"></span>
```

Comment: your usage of `$parent` in you code is ideal as `$data` refers to current looping instance as your `adultsNo` in root level (viewModel) . In short your usage of binding context's depend upon how you build your viewmodel . cheers

Comment: Thanks supercool - is there a way to adapt my viewModel to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: $data is not required in your sample. Simply using val/text will suffice.

Comment: when do I use $data then? Also can you point me in the direction of how to achieve what I was looking for (although not needing $data does tidy it up a bit)

Comment: and why the hell do I have a downVote?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is your goal to not reference $parent at all in your HTML and somehow get access to the outer context inside the foreach?

Comment: getting rid of $parent is the main aim now, also would love to get it to a single binding

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the $data by doing the following in your html:

foreach : { data: adults, as: 'adult' }

the $parent is not as clean as far as I know.  The only way is to define the parent item for each item in the array.

```js
//used to abstract out the jQuery dependancies - just in case at some point in the future jQUery is replaced with another library.
function activeClassSingle(element, standardClass, activeClass){
    $(element).siblings().removeClass(activeClass).addClass(standardClass);
    $(element).removeClass(standardClass).addClass(activeClass);
}



//helper class in a helper file
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonGroupChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
    viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                click: function () {
                    value(allBindingsAccessor.get('val'));
                }
            }
        };
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor,
        allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
    viewModel, bindingContext) {          
        if (allBindingsAccessor.get("val") == ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
           activeClassSingle(element, "btn-info", "btn-success");
        }        
    }
}

//raw data
 var adults = [
    {val: 1, text: "1"},
    {val: 2, text: "2"},
    {val: 3, text: "3"},
    {val: 4, text: "4"},
    {val: 5, text: "5"},
    {val: 6, text: "5+"}
    ];


//viewmodel etc.
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.adultsNo = ko.observable(2);
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-bind="foreach: { data: adults, as: 'adult' }">
            <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bind="buttonGroupChecked: $parent.adultsNo, val: adult.val, text: $data.text"></div>
        </div>
        <span data-bind="text: adultsNo"></span>
```

Comment: sorry vlad but I do not get what you have actually done here - I was aiming for less intrusive binding in the DOM - also in the comments ChromsonChris pointed out that I do not need to use $data at all with my current set-up. Have I missed something?

Comment: I read my own prejudice into the question.  I got away from $data because I wanted something more readable say like binding a list of adults with an element of age: "adult.age",  "age", or "$data.age".  I like "adult.age".  Sorry I missed the intent of the question.